# Trying to make a countdown on a filter in Lens Studio, countdown stuck

Tags: javascript, if-statement, timer, var, snapchat

Im trying to make a countdown in lens studio that ends on a speficic time, but when i try to edit the timer it only goes from 58:45 and 57:00 minutes. How do i fix it, here is the script.

Iv`e tried many things but it wont work. I tried to correct the startTimer function to properly calculate the time remaining until the target timestamp.

Iv`e also tried to make sure to use the correct variable for the countdown duration.

This is the timer.js:

```
// ---- Start Timer Object Script ----

//@input Asset.Texture[] timerTextures
//@input Component.SpriteVisual[] columns

var maxTime = 0;
var timerType = 'countdown';
var time = 0;
var minutes = 0;
var seconds = 0;
var minutesTens = 0;
var minutesOnes = 0;
var secondsTens = 0;
var secondsOnes = 0;

global.timerSeconds = 0;
global.timerActive = false;

global.startTimer = function(targetTimestamp, type) {
if (!global.timerActive) {
    if (type === 'stopwatch' || type === 'countdown') {
        timerType = type;
        print(timerType + ' is starting');
        global.timerActive = true;

        // Calculate the initial time difference
        const currentDate = new Date().getTime();
        const initialTimeDifference = targetTimestamp - currentDate;
        
        // For countdown, set the countdown duration in seconds
        time = type === 'countdown' ? Math.max(initialTimeDifference / 1000, 0) : 0;  // Ensure time is non-negative
        global.timerSeconds = time;

        updateTime.reset(0);
    } else {
        print('type invalid');
    }
} else {
    print('timer already started');
}
}

 global.stopTimer = function(callback) {
if (global.timerActive) {
    global.timerActive = false;
    print(timerType + ' finished');
    if (callback) {
        callback(arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3], arguments[4], arguments[5]);
    }
} else {
    print('No stopwatch/countdown initialized');
}
}

var updateTime = script.createEvent("DelayedCallbackEvent");
updateTime.bind(function(eventData, callback, cb) {
minutes = Math.floor(time / 60)
seconds = time - (minutes * 60)

if (minutes > 9) {
    minutesTens = Number(String(minutes).charAt(0));
    minutesOnes = Number(String(minutes).charAt(1));
} else {
    minutesTens = 0;
    minutesOnes = Number(String(minutes).charAt(0));
}
if (seconds > 9) {
    secondsTens = Number(String(seconds).charAt(0));
    secondsOnes = Number(String(seconds).charAt(1));
} else {
    secondsTens = 0;
    secondsOnes = Number(String(seconds).charAt(0));
}

updateTimerSprites();

// start change time
if (global.timerActive) {
    if (timerType === 'countdown') {
        time--;
        global.timerSeconds--;
        if (time >= 0) {
            updateTime.reset(1);
        } else {
            global.stopTimer();
        }
    } else {
        time++;
        global.timerSeconds++;
        if (time <= maxTime) {
            updateTime.reset(1);
        } else {
            global.stopTimer();
        }
    }
}
});

function updateTimerSprites() {
script.columns[0].mainPass.baseTex = script.timerTextures[secondsOnes];
script.columns[1].mainPass.baseTex = script.timerTextures[secondsTens];
script.columns[2].mainPass.baseTex = script.timerTextures[minutesOnes];
script.columns[3].mainPass.baseTex = script.timerTextures[minutesTens];
}
```

And this is Script.js:

```
const targetTimestamp = new Date("2024-01-01T00:00:00Z").getTime();
global.startTimer(targetTimestamp, 'countdown');
```